# How can I get data off a website like Apple or Google with javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, get

Do you know how I can get data from a website like Apple or Google with javascript? 
'data' meaning text

I have tried checking many other forums, but when I test their code, the console prints:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.apple.com.au/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
makeXMLRequest();
 function makeXMLRequest() {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.apple.com.au",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: You will probably find that you will be unable to do this from JavaScript accessed via a browser.  The apple site has a header that disallows access via the mechanism you are attempting to use.  You may need to use a different technology.  For more information on what I mean, google 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
 is a fondamental concept in web development.

Basically, most companies don't want to serve content to client-side application that don't belong to them, mainly for security, and also for server load. That is why when using XHR from, let's say, `localhost`, you won't be able to get content from `google.com`.

That is not the case of all web pages though - public educational APIs often configure their CORS headers so that their content is avaiable wherever.

Demo time:

```js
// get rejected because of facebook's CORS policy
fetch('https://facebook.com')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);

// works fine
fetch('https://api.github.com')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```